# how can i display the input from text widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

t1 = Text(root).place(x=50,y=50,w=50,h=30)

def getdata():
    a = t1.get()
    print(a)

b1 = Button(root, text="get",comman=getdata).place(x=50, y=100, w=50, h=20)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: edit question, select code and use `Ctrl+K` to format it.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title.

Comment: you have common problem with `variable = Widget(...).place()` - you have do it in two steps - `variable = Widget(...)` and `variable.place()` because `place/pack/grid` returns `None` and you get `variable = None` and later `t1.get()` measn `None.get()` and you get your error message.

Comment: Show what you have done, and send the error message in code, not screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

In this line-

```py
t1 = Text(root).place(x=50,y=50,w=50,h=30)
```

You are creating a text element, then moving that element. The problem with your implementation is that when you call the `.place()` method, it does not return a Text object. It instead returns None (does not actually return anything).

What I think you meant to do is the following- set `t1` to the Text element, then proceed to move it with `.place()`. You can do this by assigning `t1` to the Text element and running `.place()` on `t1`:

```py
t1 = Text(root)
t1.place(x=50,y=50,w=50,h=30)
```

Comment: i want to display the text which is entered in text i don't think this would effect any @Xiddoc

Comment: @tanmaythakur it will stop the error you posted in the screenshot, I can guarantee you that.